# VLC only in Windows 7 system tray?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, vlc-media-player, notification-area

How can I set the VLC icon only in Windows 7 system tray and not duplicated also in the taskbar?

To be clear (since some of the answers seem to misunderstand what is being asked), the question is not about *minimizing to tray*, but rather to leave the VLC window open and playing a video, but not show the VLC button on the taskbar (or in the Alt-Tab list).

Comment: I’m sure it’s been asked before (I could swear I’ve seen it discussed the last time I looked into it), but at the moment, all I can find is [this single request](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=111040) for the feature which went completely ignored.

Answer (score 20):

Right-click on the tray icon and click on 'hide VLC media player in taskbar'.

Comment: That option not present for me (Win7HP and VLC 2.05)

Comment: That option hides VLC altogether!

Comment: How could we permanently hide it from taskbar?

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the VLC icon when it is running.  It will ALWAYS appear on the taskbar while it is running.

Answer (score 0):

If using a custom skin, the option is not available. When return to native (default) skin, the option is available.

You must quit VLC and restart for changes to take effect.

---

Here is a freeware alternative (Windows):

http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/trayit.html

It takes some config, but it works. I got it working by turning off the systray icon  (in VLC preferences) and restarting VLC.

Also necessary to refresh TrayIt's windows list (Windows menu).

If TrayIt closed/disappears, you can restart from the icon, or from the "TrayIt Application" option on the systray VLC icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually read the Synetech's question in full, he doesn't just want to minimize to the tray, he wants to *always* hide VLC from the taskbar.

So, at least when using a skin, there *is* an option to do this under Advanced Preferences -> Interface -> Main Interfaces -> Skins, where you can uncheck "Show VLC on the taskbar".

Unfortunately, I don't see a way of achieving this same result in Qt, though -- that is, when *not* using a skin -- unless you install some third party tool to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we can hide the VLC taskbar icon by clicking on "Hide VLC Media player".

```
Step 1: Click on "show hidden icons(at exactly right side bottom corner)".
Step 2: Right click on VLC icon.
Step 3: Say Hide VLC Media player from taskbar.
```

I hope it's useful.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Super User. Thank you for the answer, but this information is already in [another answer](http://superuser.com/a/471775/461558), albeit without 'show hidden icons'. Perhaps you could add something to differentiate your answer?